# Creating and writing into .plist with Terminal or bash script

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, info.plist

I need to create a .plist file during post install and the only option I can use is a bash script. I have to create a foo.plist into `/Library/launchAgents` with a bash script and I've used the following command:

```
cd /Library/launchAgents
touch foo.plist
```

now I need to write contents into this .plist file for example like this:

```
".plist contents" >> foo.plist
```

Is there a command that can do this in the terminal?

Comment: Where are the plist contents that you want to write into the plist? I mean do you have a list of them in a file? With their corresponding valuse? Are they in a shell variable? Why do you have to use `bash`, why can't you use an editor?

Comment: yeah i have a working .plist file . I need to used bash because installer will run this bash script. so to automate the process as a post install step during installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question doesn't specify very well what you have got, or why you need to do it in `bash`, but if you must do it that way, you can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=2.12
cat > foo.plist <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>BuildAliasOf</key>
        <string>ProEditor</string>
        <key>BuildVersion</key>
        <value>$VERSION</value>
</dict>
</plist>
EOF
```

So, you save this in a file called `Buildplist` and then do this to make it executable

```
chmod +x Buildplist
```

and then you run it by typing this:

```
./Buildplist
```

You can make it write the plist file directly into `/Library/launchAgents` by changing the second line to something like this:

```
cat > /Library/launchAgents/yourApp/yourApp.plist <<EOF
```

You can make it accept parameters too. So if you want to pass the Author as the first parameter, you can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=2.12
AUTHOR="$1"
cat > foo.plist <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>BuildAliasOf</key>
        <string>ProEditor</string>
        <key>BuildVersion</key>
        <value>$VERSION</value>
        <author>$AUTHOR</author>
</dict>
</plist>
EOF
```

and then run

```
./Buildplist "Freddy Frog"
```

to pass "Freddy Frog" as the author.

If you want to avoid overwriting any plist file that already exists, you can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PLISTFILE="/Library/launchAgents/yourApp/yourApp.plist"

# If plist already exists, do not overwrite, just exit quietly
[ -f "$PLISTFILE" ] && exit

cat > "$PLISTFILE" <<EOF
...
...
EOF
```

I put the name of the plist file in a variable to simplify maintenance, and avoid typing it twice.

Comment: "Why I have to do this?" because i want to execute a script during my application install . when installer "which is a DMG" and "PKG" installer completes installation i need to execute this bash script at the end to put this .plist file in /Library..

Comment: is there any way i can check and skip if file already exists??

Comment: Yes, of course. I have added a little extra at the end to show how to do that. Please have another look.

Comment: `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` is better.

Answer (score 23):

**PlistBuddy** is what you want.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy Info.plist
File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: Info.plist
```

Then add an entry to the file like this,

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'add CFBundleIdenfier string com.tencent.myapp' Info.plist
```

By the way, `man plist`, `man plutil` may be helpful for you.

```
Command Format:
    Help - Prints this information
    Exit - Exits the program, changes are not saved to the file
    Save - Saves the current changes to the file
    Revert - Reloads the last saved version of the file
    Clear [<Type>] - Clears out all existing entries, and creates root of Type
    Print [<Entry>] - Prints value of Entry.  Otherwise, prints file
    Set <Entry> <Value> - Sets the value at Entry to Value
    Add <Entry> <Type> [<Value>] - Adds Entry to the plist, with value Value
    Copy <EntrySrc> <EntryDst> - Copies the EntrySrc property to EntryDst
    Delete <Entry> - Deletes Entry from the plist
    Merge <file.plist> [<Entry>] - Adds the contents of file.plist to Entry
    Import <Entry> <file> - Creates or sets Entry the contents of file

Entry Format:
    Entries consist of property key names delimited by colons.  Array items
    are specified by a zero-based integer index.  Examples:
        :CFBundleShortVersionString
        :CFBundleDocumentTypes:2:CFBundleTypeExtensions

Types:
    string
    array
    dict
    bool
    real
    integer
    date
    data

Examples:
    Set :CFBundleIdentifier com.apple.plistbuddy
        Sets the CFBundleIdentifier property to com.apple.plistbuddy
    Add :CFBundleGetInfoString string "App version 1.0.1"
        Adds the CFBundleGetInfoString property to the plist
    Add :CFBundleDocumentTypes: dict
        Adds a new item of type dict to the CFBundleDocumentTypes array
    Add :CFBundleDocumentTypes:0 dict
        Adds the new item to the beginning of the array
    Delete :CFBundleDocumentTypes:0 dict
        Deletes the FIRST item in the array
    Delete :CFBundleDocumentTypes
        Deletes the ENTIRE CFBundleDocumentTypes array
```

Comment: I found this article incredibly helpful in addition to this answer: https://medium.com/@marksiu/what-is-plistbuddy-76cb4f0c262d